# iPhone iOS 12.0 update will not sign into Apple ID, cannot access App Store or sync contacts from Gmail

Tags: apple-id, contacts, gmail, ios

I updated my iPhone to iOS 12 and noticed first that all my contacts no longer syncing from my Gmail account. I also cannot access the App Store.

In Settings I have tried multiple times to sign in with my Apple ID but it just doesn't work.  I have restarted my device multiple times.  There isn't an option under Contacts in the settings to set the default.  I've tried over wifi and over cellular, nothing is working.

What else can I do to try resolving this?

Comment: what does it say when you try to log in app store

Comment: In settings it is asking for me to sign into my iPhone with my apple id, when I do, it thinks about it for a few seconds saying signing into icloud but then just  goes back to the main settings screen.  When I try to open the app store, it just says its unavailable.

Comment: are you saying your iCould is not working

Comment: The thing in settings says "Sign in to your iPhone" and below that it says "Set up iCloud, the App Store, and..." When I tap that it goes to a screen that says "Apple ID", so I enter my Apple ID and PW and then it goes to another screen, that has that thinking circle, or working on it circle and underneath the circle it says "signing into icloud".  it does that for only a few seconds before popping back to the main settings screen.  I suppose icloud also isn't working but I don't really use icloud for much.